# Is it possible to bulk validate a records before submit using recordEditForm component?

Tags: lightning-recordeditform

*Lightning Component*

```html
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editFormAccount"  objectApiName="Account">       
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered" style="min-width: 100px;">
        <thead >                            
            <tr class="slds-no-hover">
                <th>Account Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><lightning:inputField fieldName="Name"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Save" class="slds-m-top_medium" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

I tried to create multiple accounts by using above code, by adding rows dynamically.
for ex.
In Row.1 I filled every fields ,
In Row.2 I left one field to fill i.e required.

The issues is when I tried to Submit both records, It's giving me the standard error on Row.2  "Please fill the require field", but Row.1 record Got created.

When I fill the required field on Row.2 and again click on Submit, then again Row.1 and Row.2 records got created.

So it become 3 records, so need to validate both records before submit by providing the standard error on field.

**This is Controller I used.**

```js
handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {    
     component.find('editFormAccount').submit();
}
```

I am new salesforce lightning component, Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should validate each form before submit by validation logic. fire your standard validation message by error toast event if your validation fails. here is validation logic. you can use `required` attribute for your inputfield in lightning recordform too

CMP

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:availableForFlowScreens,lightning:actionOverride"
            controller="SeTesting"
            access="global">
<aura:iteration items="1,2,3" var="iterate">
    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm" objectApiName="Account">         
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="NameField" fieldName="Name"/>
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:iteration>
```

**Controller**

```
handleSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
    if(helper.validateform(component)){
        component.find("editForm").forEach( form =>{
            form.submit();
        });
        }else{
           helper.showerrorToast(component);  // fire your toast Error message  here 
        }

}
```

**helper**

```
validateform: function(component) {
     var reqfelds = [].concat(component.find('NameField'))
     for(var i=0;i<reqfelds.length;i++){
         if($A.util.isEmpty(reqfelds[i].get("v.value")))   
             return false;
     }
     return true;
},
showerrorToast : function(component) {
var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
toastEvent.setParams({
    "title": "Required Field Error!",
    "type": "error"
    "message": "add your standard error message."
});
toastEvent.fire();
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

It Works . just have one issue.

When I tried to hit submit after multiple records it is giving me the error.

$controller$save [component.find(...).setError is not a function] to set the Standard error message.
do we need to iterate this line.

component.find('standerrorMessage').setError('set your standardmessage');

Comment: updated my answer, if it works for you please upvote the answer to help other community members

Comment: It works, Thank you very much.

Comment: Can we show this error message near row or input field based on multiple field validation?

Comment: Hi , Can we show this error message near row?

Comment: did you try with `required=true` for `lightning:inputfield`?

Comment: Yes, but it is only throwing error message when we hover over the input field.